# Access IIF statement using dates

Tags: date, ms-access, iif

Can someone help me with why I'm getting result of #Error on this IIf statement?

```
ENDDT: IIf([dbo_Pr_EmpPayData_T]![dteTerminationDate]="9/9/9999",
Null,Format([dbo_Pr_EmpPayData_T]![dteTerminationDate],"mm/dd/yyyy"))
```

What I want to do....  If the field contains 9/9/9999 do nothing, give me a blank field.  Otherwise, I want the date in the field and I wanted it formatted mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose your 9/9/9999 with # instead of in quotes.

Comment: Well now I feel stupid, lol...

Thank you it worked perfectly this time!